# Filter column with other column in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am learning SQL and I want to use `ReportsTo` value to get the `EmployeeId` and use it to get `FullName` without using `JOIN`. The final results should show who has how many subordinates.

| EmployeeID | FullName | ReportsTo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Nancy Davolio | 2 |
| 2 | Andrew Fuller | NULL |
| 3 | Janet Leverling | 2 |
| 4 | Margaret Peacock | 2 |
| 5 | Steven Buchanan | 2 |
| 6 | Michael Suyama | 5 |
| 7 | Robert King | 5 |
| 8 | Laura Callahan | 2 |
| 9 | Anne Dodsworth | 5 |

```sql
Select
    (Select FirstName + ' ' + LastName
     From Employees
     Where EmployeeID = ReportsTo) as EmployeeName,
    Count(EmployeeID) as SubordinateAmount,
    ReportsTo
From 
    Employees
Where 
    ReportsTo is not Null
Group By 
    ReportsTo
```

The result should be like:

| FullName | Subordinates |
| --- | --- |
| Andrew Fuller | 5 |
| Steven Buchanan | 3 |

I have tried using a subquery by `EmployeeID = ReportsTo`, but it returns `Null`, and I can't figure out what to use.

Comment: Please can you edit your question and tag the DBMS you are using ?

Comment: what do you mean by DBMS? I really dont know the terminology

Comment: The database you are using, SQL Server, Postgresql, mysql ...

Comment: Im not using any specific SQL's, rather learning SQL from scratch using Microsoft SQL Server Manager Studio, I have no knowledge on which DBMS this will be useful for. I did see this on several SQL options while coding on Python, but i never bothered tto continue with them

Comment: is there a much simpler way to do it? I am yet to learn recursives and i was expected to get the result with group by and subqueries somehow

Comment: If you're using SSMS why have you tagged MySQL? SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) is an IDE-like appliyfor SQL Server; you can't connect to MySQL with SSMS.

Comment: I didnt lol, someone else did i think

Comment: If you tackle this one step at a time, then you'll like reach your required result yourself.  My first suggestion is, attempt to write a query that returns you just the "Subordinates" column (that you show in your expected result), with the relevant values.  How might you achieve that?  That is step 1

Comment: Subordinates of Steven should be 3?

Comment: sorrry for type @lara19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this i guess:

```sql
select *
into #data
from (
    VALUES  (1, N'Nancy Davolio', N'2')
    ,   (2, N'Andrew Fuller', NULL)
    ,   (3, N'Janet Leverling', N'2')
    ,   (4, N'Margaret Peacock', N'2')
    ,   (5, N'Steven Buchanan', N'2')
    ,   (6, N'Michael Suyama', N'5')
    ,   (7, N'Robert King', N'5')
    ,   (8, N'Laura Callahan', N'2')
    ,   (9, N'Anne Dodsworth', N'5')
) t (EmployeeID,FullName,ReportsTo)

select COUNT(*)
,   (select fullname from #data d2 where d2.EmployeeID = d.reportsto)
from #data d
where ReportsTo is not null
group by reportsto
```

It fetches the necessary data by correlated subquery. But i'm not sure why the reluctance to use a join, it's "usually" better and more clearer to use

Comment: It's because this is a class assignment.